# Определение геопозиции десктопа

Tags: геолокация, gps

Существуют ли какие-либо методы для определения геопозиции десктопа или ноутбука? То есть устройства, в котором нет GPS модуля. На пример ноутбук должен получить координаты своего местоположения и дальше работать с ними. Возможно ли это как-нибудь реализовать?

Comment: Может по IP и окружающим WiFi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хотел собрать информацию по районам с которых ко мне заходят пользователи.
Точных данных по району не нашел. Тестировал несколько сервисов:

1. https://freegeoip.net/
2. https://ipinfo.io/
3. http://www.geoplugin.com/
4. https://www.maxmind.com/

Мобильные устройства точно определяет [Навигатор](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition), [Яндекс](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/geolocation)

Вывод: определить у десктопа точно можно только город. 
p.s. Да и на 90%.